# Prove that $u-i$ generates a maximal ideal of $A.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

> Let $A = \frac {\Bbb C[X,Y]} {\left ( X^2 + Y^2 - 1 \right )},$ $x,y$ denote the images of $X,Y$ in $A$ respectively. If $u = x + iy,$ then prove that

> (a) $u$ is a umit in $A,$ and

> (b) $u-i$ generates a maximal ideal of $A.$

I assume by image of $X$ and $Y$ it is meant that the image of $X$ and $Y$ under the quotient map $f : \Bbb C[X,Y] \longrightarrow A$ defined by $$P(X,Y) \longmapsto P(X,Y) + \left (X^2+Y^2 - 1 \right ),\ P(X,Y) \in \Bbb C[X,Y].$$ Then $x = X + \left (X^2 + Y^2 - 1 \right )$ and $y = Y + \left (X^2 + Y^2 - 1 \right ).$ If we denote the identity of $A$ i.e. $1 + \left (X^2 + Y^2 - 1 \right )$ by $\overline {1},$ then we get $x^2 + y^2 = \overline {1}\ $ i.e. $\ u \cdot (x-iy) = \overline {1}.$ Since $x-iy \in A$ (Since it is the image of $X - i Y \in \Bbb C[X,Y]$ under the quotient map $f$), so it follows that $u$ is a unit in $A,$ which proves (a).

How do I prove $(b)$? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** $:$ $A$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C [x,y],$ as rings. Any maximal ideal of $A$ corresponds to the maximal ideal of $\Bbb C[X,Y]$ containing $\left (X^2 + Y^2 - 1 \right ).$ So $x+iy-i$ generates a maximal ideal of $A$ iff $\left (X+i(Y-1), X^2 +Y^2 -1 \right )$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb C[X,Y].$

Comment: What do you get if you quotient $A$ by $(u-i)$, or equivalently, if you quotient $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ by $\left (X+i(Y-1), X^2 +Y^2 -1 \right)$?